# What cast should I use at r.nextInt()?

Tags: java, android

I have tried to build a program where you give a maximum and a minimum to generate a random number between them. Eclipse says that I have to add a cast to `r.nextInt()`. I did but I don´t know what to use instead of Object here:

```
int result = ((Object) r).nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

(cast is already added by Eclipse). Thanks for your help.

This is the important code.

```
public void ButtonKlick (View view) {
    int max;
    EditText maxText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.maximum);
    if (maxText.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    max = Integer.parseInt(maxText.getText().toString());

    int min;
    EditText minText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.minimum);
    if (minText.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    min = Integer.parseInt(minText.getText().toString());

    Random r = new Random();
    int result = ((Object) r).nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

    EditText resultText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_result);
    resultText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

Comment: As it should simply be `int result = r.nextInt...` - what to tell? Cast to `Random`? Instead of `r` try without variable `r`: `new Random().nextInt`

Comment: You shouldn't have to cast. As a matter of fact, your current code won't compile because `Object` has no method `nextInt`. It is enough having `int result = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;`

Comment: Yasmani If i tipe this in:   int result = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min; Eclipse says: The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random and underlines nextInt red. There are 2 quick fixes availalbe: 1-create method nextInt(int) and 2-add cast to r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have defined your own class called Random. Don't do that. Rename it. Then r.nextInt() will work without a cast.

Comment: Thanks, I changed all the .xml and .java file names. Now it is working very good.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
Random r = new Random();
int result = ((Object) r).nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

to

```
Random r = new Random();
int result = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

R.nextInt() returns an integer

At the top of the page (above class definition but below the package definition), you should see some imports. You want to make sure that this is up there:

```
package com.example.yourproject;

import java.util.Random;
...

public class yourclass {
...
```

Comment: sorry it didn´t work, eclipse continues saying add cast to r. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Are you sure you're importing java.util.Random?

Comment: no i don´t have java.util.Random imported. how do i import it?

Comment: When I add import java.util.Random; it says import java.util.Random; conflicts with a type defined in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast that at all. You are getting the next integer from the random number generator, and setting an int to that value. It should just be

```
int result = r.nextInt(max - (min + 1)) + min;
```

That will give you a random number between max and min + 1